# Data collections/lists software

Tags: information-management, collection-manager

I am looking for a software that will allow to create collections/lists of data.

Some features:

Each collection would allow me to define which table/DB columns that collection would have to hold data on.

For example a **Book collection** might have a

- title
- ISBN #
- author
- description
- publish date
- description

A collection of **online user accounts** might have the columns

- name
- website URL
- login name
- password
- notes
- description

Then when adding a new collection record it would only show the fields for that collection.  Same with viewing the collection records.

Each collection would have these basic screens

- create collection record
- edit record
- list view of collection records
- detail view for viewing a collection record

---

I have considered building this software as a web based app but do not have the time now.  Does anyone know if such an app exist for Windows or web based?

Comment: This is just the definition of a very simple database app. So Google for something like "simple web based database"

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried [**Simitless**](https://simitless.com/)? It is a platform that enables you to create your own data collection easily and fast. And it answers all of your criteria:

- You can create your collection and define the columns that your collection would have to hold. The way it works is that you get predifned spreadsheet-columns-like fields that you can select from to track/collect only the data you need.
- Each of your collections would have the screens that you need:

  create record,

  [image]

  edit record,

  [image]

  list view of collection records,

  [image]

  detail view,

  [image]
- You can import and export your data at any time.
- You can collect and organize the data the way you want to as you make the app yourself (you can use templates, though, there are quite a few of them).
- As it is web based, it is always accessible be it from a desktop or a mobile device.

**Full disclosure: I am part of the startup that designed that platform.** We launched recently and are still in beta.

If you want to see what it looks like, I have made two templates for the use cases that you described in your question, the [Book Collection](https://simitless.com/en/templates?or=st&preview=templates-book-collection) and the [Online User Accounts](https://simitless.com/en/templates?or=st&preview=templates-online-user-accounts) template. Since these are just templates, you can modify them as you see fit. It might be just what you are looking for. If you need any help, I can definitely give you a hand. Just get in touch.

Answer (score 0):

## FileMaker

The [FileMaker tools](http://www.filemaker.com) allow you to define tables in which to store rows (records). Both desktop and server editions are available.

FileMaker is not fully relational, meaning it has only a rudimentary ability to link records between tables.

Very easy to get started with.

## 4D

The [4D family of tools](http://www.4d.com) are similar in basic ideas to FileMaker, but much more powerful, fully relational, and somewhat more complicated to get started with.